# AVCaptureVideoOrientation never changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, avcapturesession

I need to get the device orientation, but, probably because the app I'm developing only supports the portrait orientation, it never seems to change. I've tried `[AVCaptureConnection videoOrientation]`, `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`, to no avail. The orientation always says "portrait".

Is there a way to get the *real* orientation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I get your question correct or not, but try this. It may help you.

**In .h file:-**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer;
```

**In .m file:-**

```
// CHECK FOR YOUR APP
self.previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
//self.previewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

// CHECK FOR YOUR APP
//[self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];   // Comment-out to hide preview layer
```